# Keep desktop icons as they are shortly after logging in

Tags: macos, finder, icon, desktop, file

The following image shows two screenshots of my Mac's desktop whilst starting up. The first is a few seconds after starting, whilst the other one is a few seconds to shutdown.

I prefer the icons on the left, from the first screenshot. I would like to keep them as default. How can I show the first set of icons as default?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is because it loads the previews of the files, which replace the default file icons. To disable icon previews on the desktop, click on the desktop, press ⌘J and uncheck ‘Show icon previews’.

[image]